# What is templates/system directory in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: javascript, joomla1.5

What is templates/system directory in Joomla 1.5? Is it system template or common directory for all templates? May I put some javascript widgets there?

Answer (score 1):

`templates/system` directory in Joomla 1.5 is not a complete template which you can apply likewise other templates - `beez` or `ja_purity`.

If you place the templateDetails.xml file in the system directory, it will also be listed in the template manager and you can make this template as default too. But, this template is almost blank. Styles and images are very less. `index.php` file in this template is just including `component.php` file which is just importing css only.
Hope this clarify your doubts. :)